# Restoring deleted files removes them from the git repo

Tags: git

I accidentally deleted a directory from my git repo. I restored it with the git CLI, but from then on git no longer recognized it as part of the repo.

My steps in more detail:

1. the directory was deleted
2. running `git status` showed the dir and its files as "deleted"
3. I ran `git reset --hard` to undo the delete
4. the dir and files were restored; however, they were no longer part of the repo, but listed as "untracked"

(As a note, the affected files have been in the repo for a long time and have not been touched recently, so this is not an issue of losing uncommited changes.)

I already fixed the problem by re-cloning my remote repo and re-applying my local changes as patches. But still, I'd like to understand what happened. Was this my mistake, should I have used another command to undo the delete?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `git reset --hard` "...Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since <commit> are discarded." [(git-scm)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). This means your repository will be on the exact state of your last commit (your branches HEAD). The only explanation for your situation is that your folder was not part of the repo in said commit, i.e. was removed from the repository in a previous commit. Are you sure this did not happen?

Comment: Yes, completely sure. As I said, I fixed this by cloning my remote repo again and replaying the local commits; the resulting working copy contained the folder as part of the repo, which would not be the case if it had been removed by a commit.

Comment: I see. And can you reproduce this on your fresh clone?

Comment: No, when I delete the folder and run git reset --hard, the folder just rappears in the repo as it should.

Comment: "Untracked" literally means "not in the index" (with the additional condition that, for Git to *complain* about not being in the index, the path must not be listed in an "ignore" file). For `git reset` to restore the file to the work tree, it must first write it to the index. So the only way for this to happen is to (somehow) reset using a *different* index file (which is possible but tricky) or for your index file to have been clobbered, e.g., due to some background thing messing with your files (dropbox et al: never put Git repos into dropbox).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details... and for the record, I'm of course not working in a dropbox directory ;)